# What does exponent notation mean in logic/discrete math?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, notation

My discrete math textbook defines an expression as:

$A^C \cup (A-B)$, but I am not sure how to read $A^C$. Does anyone understand what this notation means in the context of logic/discrete math?

Comment: It's the complement.

Answer (score 1):

The set $A^{\mathrm{C}}$ is defined to be the set of everything that is *not* in $A$. If $U$ is your universe, then $$A^{\mathrm{C}} := U - A$$
It's called the [complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)) of a set.